# Expression-based labeling in QFIELD 0.8.2 not working

Tags: qgis, qfield

It seems that labeling is not possible in the actual versions of QFIELD any longer (I'am working with 0.8.2 now) when there is a scale-based expression There is no labeling in this case although the new "busy-indicator" shows after disappearing - that rendering /labeling came to an end.
Working for example with a simple `ASE WHEN $scale <2000 THEN "fieldname"` expression does work in QGIS 2.14/2.16.2 but not in QFIELD (its the same with using variables instead of numbers for the scale). Simple labeling without expression works without problems.

*(I am using a sqlite-database with a multipolygon-geometry for the test with Android 5.0.1.)
(In my regular project I use more complicated conditions to build different contents by a scale-based expression - this very simple example might have worked by other settings in the labeling-gui - but I tried to find out where the problem lies)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QField is based on the code for QGIS 3 which removed some deprecated variables, among them `$scale`. These variables have replacements which are prefixed with an `@`.

Just replace `$scale` with `@map_scale`.

```
CASE WHEN @map_scale < 2000 THEN "fieldname"
```

An alternative approach is to use rule-based labeling, where it is possible to specify the scale in which a rule is applicable for each rule separately.